# @PreMatching not working with Dynamic Binding in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm trying to sanitize the calls to an API before they get to the resource method. I've decided that the best way to do that is by creating filters and binding them dynamically. However, the `@PreMatching` annotation only work if I make them global. My code is the next one:

The filter:

```
@PreMatching
public class FilterTest implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException {

        UriBuilder ub = crc.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder();
        ub.replaceQueryParam("count", 20);
        crc.setRequestUri(ub.build());

    }

}
```

The Dynamic Binding class:

```
@Provider
public class DynamicTest implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo ri, FeatureContext fc) {
        if (MyResourceClass.class.equals(ri.getResourceClass())){
            fc.register(FilterTest.class);

        }
    }

}
```

The Jersey Application file:

```
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        ...
        register(DynamicTest.class);
    }

}
```

The error:

```
HTTP 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method could be called only in pre-matching request filter.
```

What can I do?